# How to avoid Firefox re-using a Firefox instance on another machine when sharing the same X11 DISPLAY?

Tags: browser, xorg, mobaxterm, xdg

With two Linux servers I experience over X11 some very surprising behaviour. Here the details about the situation:

1. I have two remote Linux machines, *Paula* (RHEL6) and *Marie* (CentOS7).
2. I connect to them from a Windows 7 machine (*Walter*) via MobaXterm. In both SSH/Shell sessions I set the DISPLAY variables to my local Windows machine.
3. Through the MobaXterm shell window for the Linux machine *Marie* I start on *Marie* Firefox. On my local machine *Walter* a Firefox window opens (which of course runs on *Marie*). So far so good.
4. Now I issue in the MobaXterm shell window for the other Linux machine *Paula* `xdg-open www.google.com`.
5. This opens a new tab **in *Marie*'s** Firefox!

I totally didn't expect this! (I assume *Paula*'s Firefox (invoked via `xdg-open`) passes the open request to the X11 system on *Walter* which then channels it to the browser on *Marie*.)

And I do not want this to happen. How can I force `xdg-open` on *Paula* to (re-)use a browser on *Paula*, i.e a browser on the machine the `xdg-open` command was issued on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xdg-open has no concept of windows, machines, or even browsers. In the end, all it does (after passing through some other tools, looking up the mimetype, etc.) is simply run:

```
/usr/bin/firefox http://www.google.com
```

Whether Firefox will use independent instances for each $DISPLAY or whether it will use a single instance is a decision made entirely by Firefox. By default, it always contacts the existing instance over IPC and asks it to open a new window/tab.

The way this is implemented, in Firefox specifically, is indeed [through X11 as an IPC channel](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/WeirdFirefoxRemoteControl) – it communicates with the existing instance by searching for an existing window and setting certain X properties on it. Unfortunately it doesn't check whether that window's WM_CLIENT_MACHINE actually matches the host it's running on.

(The reason it uses a single instance is because it cannot easily share the "profile" (settings files) between multiple processes, and it cannot easily connect to multiple $DISPLAYs from a single process either. Both are technically possible to implement, but probably not seen as *nearly* enough of a benefit to justify the work needed.)

To avoid this you can set `MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1`, or if you run `firefox` directly via CLI, you can use `--no-remote` which avoids the IPC. However, it will *always* try to start a new instance, even if one is already running on the *same* system. There doesn't seem to be a good way to limit the X11-based remote control to the same host, short of patching `XRemoteClient.cpp`.

Comment: Interesting! I understand that it is related to Firefox and not to xdg-open. So how can I tell **Firefox on *Paula*** to not hand the request over to a **Firefox on *Marie***, but open its own window? - Note: Both remote machines (Paula &Marie) share the same DISPLAY (Walter).

Comment: Ah, I probably misunderstood your question a bit (got the servers and Firefox instances backwards). I've updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [@grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) provided is complete. However because there doesn't seem to be a general solution I want to add how I ended up solving my problem:

I use two different browsers on the two remote systems *Paula* and *Marie*: On one I use Firefox, on the other I use Chrome - and I set the `BROWSER` environment variable on each system accordingly.

This way *Paula*'s xdg-open uses *Paula*'s Chrome and *Marie*'s xdg-open uses *Marie*'s Firefox.